# Parsing an XML file stored in the Documents directory of an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

NSXMLParser has three types of init.

-> init

-> initWith Data

-> initWithContents of URL

---

=> But my xml file is stored at Application's Document directory, so how to parse a file which is stored at "Doc Dir"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

nsdata can be initialize with the contents of a file.  Use the initWithContentsOfFile instance method with NSDAta and supply that to nsxmlparser's initWithData method:

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someFile"
                                                      ofType:@"xml"];
NSData * fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSXMLParser * parser = [NSXMLParser initWithData:fileData];
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I completely forgot that. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You beat me to it, so I added my code to your answer. Please edit as you see fit. :)