# How to parse an XML file with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsxmlparser

I have a file called sample.xml and I need to retrieve the contents in that file, using `NSXMLParser`. I tried parsing the XML file by way of a URL earlier, but now I have an XML file. Can somebody tell me how to parse when I have a file? I am Using Xcode4 and iOS SDK 4.3 Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSXMLParser on the iPhone, how do i use it given a xml file (newb here :\)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone-how-do-i-use-it-given-a-xml-file-newb-here)

Comment: Further details: [Parsing an XML File Stored in the Documents Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324404/parsing-an-xml-file-stored-in-the-documents-directory-of-an-iphone-application) [Parsing a Local XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918394/parsing-a-local-xml-file-in-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

When you parsed your data with an URL you should have done something like that:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<#(NSURL *)#>]];

// Tell NSXMLParser that this class is its delegate
[parser setDelegate:self];


[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; 
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; 
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];   

// Kick off file parsing
[parser parse];

//[parser setDelegate:nil];
[parser release];
```

To parse a file, you simply have to transform the first line and replace `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<#(NSURL *)#>]` with `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:<#(NSString *)#>]` where the `NSString` is the path to your file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the  url you can use this

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"xml"]];
NSURL *baseURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following tutorials for reading and parsing `XML` files in Objective-C.

[**Reading from a XML file in iOS.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/09/reading-from-xml-file-in-objective-c/)

[**Objective C: Parsing an XML file**](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/08/04/objective-c-parsing-an-xml-file/)